# How to create another loopback interface on linux?

Tags: linux, loopback

And NO: i don't ask about virtual IP. I need 2 different devices lo1 and lo2 to define different mtu and qdisc on them. Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need a **loopback** device, or do you just need a spare virtual interface?  Perhaps you a **dummy** interface will work?

Comment: Or better yet, a veth pair.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I have qos on a machine with several uplinks and did not need such a thing.